# HTML Select Dropdown Not Changing Page Data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a dropdown on my html page to select a year. I have a years array that looks like this:

```
0: {number: 3, name: "Year 3", subjects: Array(5)}
1: {number: 4, name: "Year 4", subjects: Array(5)}
2: {number: 5, name: "Year 5", subjects: Array(5)}
```

When a year is selected, I want it to check if that year has the selectedSubject, and if so, print the name. Here is my html code to do that:

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedYear.name">
    <option
      [label]="year.name"
      *ngFor="let year of yearDropdown"
      [selected]="selected"
      [value]="year.name"
    ></option>
  </select>

  <div class="card-body">
    {{ selectedYear.name }}
    <div *ngFor="let subject of selectedYear.subjects">
      <ng-container *ngIf="subject.name === selectedSubject.name">
        {{ subject.name }}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, it only prints out the values when first loaded, it doesn't re run the code once a year is selected. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

add an onChange to your select `<select onchange="onChange()">` like this

and try this:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from @angular/core

constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef){}

onChange() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: onChange is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: did you use the same component?

Comment: @User4612 i dint test the code, you may have to cahnge something so it matches your code, it should just gide you in the right direction, google how to add an onChange to an select in angular

Answer (score 0):

To display year drop-down dynamically you can do something like this

1. **display year dropdown with years < current year**

   var min = new Date().getFullYear(),  //current year
   stop = 2000. // year you want to stop
   select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

   for (var i = min; i >= stop; i--){
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.value = i;
   opt.innerHTML = i;
   select.appendChild(opt);
   }
2. **display year dropdown with years > current year**

   var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
   max = min + 15,
   select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

   for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.value = i;
   opt.innerHTML = i;
   select.appendChild(opt);
   }